# Git: why am I seeing a merge conflict for a valid diff?

Tags: git

Given two branches, "target" and "source", that point to the same commit.

```
git checkout target
git checkout -b source
```

And given that "source" has the following additional commits:

```
#source
a
b
```

When I cherry pick sha "a" to "target"

```
#target
git cherry-pick a #sha a1
```

Merging causes a conflict.

```
git checkout target
git merge source
# conflicts!
```

Sha b is still a valid patch to apply to a from a diff point of view though.

```
git checkout target
git cherry-pick b #sha b1
# no conflicts
```

git log graph

```
$ git log --oneline --graph target source
* 8fb4695 (HEAD -> target) a
| * af785b5 (source) b
| * 7c102f6 a
|/  
* ad8680a (master) initial commit
```

The only conflict must be that a1 is newer. What's going on here? Why would git care?

Comment: What do you mean by "equal": do the two branch names point to the *same commit*, or do they point to *different commits* (different hash IDs) whose snapshots match? Or do you mean something other than these two alternatives?

Comment: Try `git log --oneline --graph target source` and possibly post the result here to give us a real idea of your branch's topology.

Comment: @torek they point to the same commit.

Comment: @MatthieuMoy updated

Comment: it's because you're trying to add a commit that already exists most likely. if `target` and `source` point to the same commit, then they both have `a` and `b` in their history. it could also be that the changes in `a` depend on those in `b`, and the conflict is in that diff. try adding `b` first then `a` and see if you get the same error

Comment: @Derek the conflict is on commit b's changes, however. If I cherry-pick b as well, there are no conflicts

Comment: `git merge` do not look into individual commits of a branch. It only looks into branch tips and merge base. In your case it is `8fb4695`, `af785b5` and `ad8680a`. Content of `7c102f6` does not matter at all. Fact that it can be the same as `8fb4695` is not even considered. If `b` happens to alter same lines as `a`, then you will have conflict.

Comment: @steel there ya go then - you have to do it in a particular order to avoid your conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding what `git merge` and `git cherry-pick` do.

You start with the following history:

```
Init --- A'        : target
     \
      \-- A --- B  : source
```

What happens when you merge `source` into `target` is that `git` takes the two branch tips and compare them. Here the two branch are clearly distinct (and A' is not an ancestor of source, hence no fast-forward merge) thus git merges the two branch tips and record a new merge commit.

```
Init --- A' ---------- C  : target, source
     \                /
      \-- A --- B -- /
```

You may consider the two branches that were merged as distinct peers with equal rights ([as a side note you can merge more than two branches into one](https://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=139033182525831)).  When you merged, a commit with two ancestors (the branch tips of both branch of the merge (here the branch tips are A' and B)), which records the changes that occurred in both branches, was recorded.

---

If you want to avoid the merge you have to apply the commits in the source branch onto your target branch. To do that you would typically use `git rebase` not `git merge`. The fact that there is no conflict when you do the two `cherry-pick` is just because here running twice `cherry-pick` is the same as doing a rebase (but preserving the source branch)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm still not understanding. When merging, I'm designating a source and a target. I'm assuming that the source would have priority. Is that not correct? Does git treat the branches like peers?

Comment: You can indeed see the branch as distinct peers when merging. (Here a fast-forward merge cannot be done because A' has been done on branch *target* after the two branch forked). When you are merging two branches there is no notion of priority, you're creating a commit with two ancestors (the branch tips of both branch of the merge (here the branch tips are A' and B)) that will reflect the changes that occurred in both branches.

Comment: thank you, this clarifies things for me. Would you mind putting your comment in your answer? I think it's a key piece of the puzzle for me.

Comment: @steel Done. Is the integration of the comment okay with you?